# Draw Graphics in NativeActivity NDK Android

Tags: c++, graphics, android-ndk

I have a very basic question here.

How can I draw some basic geometric shapes in an NativeActivity purely using C++. I tried googling it but didnt find something concrete on this.

Any suggestions ?

Also, I want to know that `ANativeWindow_Buffer` works ?

Comment: NDK directory has two samples that does exactly what you are trying to achieve. hello-gl2 has an example of drawing triangles on OpenGL ES 2 and native-activity sample shows you how to handle native activities, as its name stands. Just combine two, should not be that hard since native-activity sample already uses OpenGL ES 2 also.

Comment: is there any other option besides using opengl ?

Comment: checkout: https://vec.io/posts/how-to-render-image-buffer-in-android-ndk-native-code